# Where can I find a reference to the possible arguments of AddBinding?

Tags: unity, input

In the new input system of Unity, the function AddBinding gets a string as an input. In
[this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html?q=AddBinding) there are several examples, such as "<Mouse>/delta" or "<Keyboard>/alt". Often, I need to add a binding and I do not know what string to use. Where can I find a reference including all possible strings that can be used as an input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating an `InputAction` in the Unity editor, then you can peek at what binding string is associated with any binding you can create in the UI:

[image: Example inspector view]

```cs
public class BindingInspector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputAction action;

    [TextArea(3,8)]
    public string binding;

    void Start() {
        if (action == null) {
            binding = "No action configured.";
            return;
        }
        string text = "";
        foreach (var binding in action.bindings) {
            text += $"{binding.ToString()}\n";
        }
        if (text == "") text = "No bindings configured.";
        binding = text;
    }
}
```